# Selenium objects out of the screen

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I currently have a selenium test that runs smooth on 1920 * 1080 resolution.
But I have a task to make this test on different common resolutions such as 
1366 *768.

Problem is when I run my Selenium test on smaller resolutions than 1920 * 1080 I can't find some elements that is below the window (as expected)
How do I solve this?

I've tried 
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight,document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight));");

To scroll to the bottom of the page but with no success.
Would appreciate help loads.
Using java, Selenium, TestNG and POM.

Comment: you mean with javascript executor you are not able to scroll

Comment: Yes that is what I meant!

Comment: plz look at the answer that i provided it will help you

Comment: Also,your last line in the question is "To scroll to the bottom of the page but with no success. Would appreciate help loads. Using java, Selenium, TestNG and POM." first part is as per question but second part is i think another question if yes then please create a separate question for that as it misleads the original question thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi to scroll please use like below

Scrolling to bottom of a page

```
driver.navigate().to(URL);
((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

Scrolling to an element on a page

```
driver.navigate().to(URL);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                "arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

Scrolling by coordinates

```
 driver.navigate().to(URL);
 ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still got one question, the site I'm currently writing tests for has 3 different scroll sections on the screen. How do I decide which "scroll" it will use? 
Appreciate all help!

Comment: i am glad that it helped you.Use Scrolling to an element on a page - this will eventually make it clear

Answer (score 0):

to scroll bottom of page, use the below code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,300)", "");
```

or

```
js.executeScript("scroll(0, 300);");
```

or

```
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```